# Extract IP from file C#

Tags: c#

There is a large text in which IP I want to extract the IP from by entering the text in the textbox and when I press the button it extracts and shows me the IP using c#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please at least provide what kind of environment you are working in and a sample of that 'large text'.

Comment: any idea how you want to solve this? any code you want to share?

Comment: IPv4? IPv6? Both?

Comment: I've linked some duplicates, that typically use a file as the source string but I trust you know how to get the text out a TextBox.Text, which is conceptually the same as having read a file into a string. Take a look at some answers that use regular expressions to scan a string for an IP and output it. They normally take the form of looking for four sets of numbers separated by a dot. If you're looking for ipv6 it'll be upto six sets of hex numbers separated by colons; I don't doubt a Google for "ipv6 Regex" will bring plenty of suggestions for how to alter your pattern to search for that

Comment: Or maybe you meant that the file path will be entered into the text box, which should mean the linked duplicates are nearly a drop-in code for what you wabt